# Does fetch() of an https: resource verify certificate chain?

Tags: tls, certificates, websocket

The `fetch()` [spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) doesn't deal with SSL/TLS since these are socket-level protocols. So I assume that it implements it's calls to lower level connection services to ensure that certificates are verified and certificate revocations are checked.

But other than a wire trace, is there a way to be reasonably certain that `fetch()` is implemented that way on any given platform? Are there other specs that document that it will happen (beyond the TLS spec)?

Comment: I'm a bit unsure what you're asking. If you want to verify the implementation, you need to check the respective browser's source. However, what you can assume is that browsers don't implement new certificate validation code per web API.

Comment: it's easy enough to test the implementation right? Fetch rides on top of the normal browser connectivity, so it's got the same validation as loading a page, image, or any other https resource.

Answer (score 1):

There is some guidance:

https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-network-fetch

> The exact determination here is up to user agents for the time being. 
>   User agents are strongly encouraged to only succeed HTTPS connections with
>   strong security properties and return network errors otherwise. 
>   Using the "deprecated" state value ought to be a temporary and last 
>   resort kind of option.